# Does Documentum 6.7 support DITA v1.2

Tags: xml, documentum, dita

We are currently using Documentum as our content repository in conjunction with XML editors like XMetal and oXygen XML. We need to upgrade our current DITA v1.0 to DITA v1.2 as the latter provides a lot of features that we need to take advantage of.

Hopefully there is someone here to help answer this question.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you got this answered over at the emc forums.  Posting here to close the loop: https://community.emc.com/message/746653#746653

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll repost as an answer so we can close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got this answered over at the emc forums. http://community.emc.com/message/746653#746653 (reported answer):

"I've just confirmed that DITA 1.2 is now supported with XML Transformation Services 6.7 SP2 P03 (included in the Content Transformation Services Patch 03, 6.7 SP2).  This patch is downloadable from the Documentum download center."